# org.xnio.channels.FixedLengthOverflowException: null

Tags: java, spring-boot, undertow, spring-boot-starter

I'm writing a video streaming service with springboot which I changed the embedded server to undertow. The service works just as I imagined but the only thing bothers me is that every time I click to play video on the page, the console logs an `org.xnio.channels.FixedLengthOverflowException` like this, though the video **does** play fine:

```
2023-09-14 17:56:03 [XNIO-1 task-1] ERROR c.s.f.w.e.GlobalExceptionHandler
 - request url '/video/play/en/big_buck_bunny.mp4', exception occur.
org.xnio.channels.FixedLengthOverflowException: null
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.write(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:100)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.write(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:150)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.write(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:240)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.write(HttpServerExchange.java:2198)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:582)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.flushInternal(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:500)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.flush(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler$StreamingResponseBodyTask.call(StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler$StreamingResponseBodyTask.call(StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler.java:98)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.lambda$startCallableProcessing$4(WebAsyncManager.java:337)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And my realated methods are below:

```
// in controller file
    @GetMapping("/play/{lang}/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> playVideo(
            @PathVariable String lang,
            @PathVariable String name,
            @RequestHeader(value = "Range", required = false) String rangeHeader
    ) {
        return videoService.loadVideo(lang, name, rangeHeader);
    }

// the method that finally returns the video stream
    private ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> loadMediaFile(Path filePath, long rangeStart, long rangeEnd) throws IOException {

        // ...

        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        String mimeType = Files.probeContentType(filePath);
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf(mimeType));
        headers.setContentLength(rangeEnd - rangeStart + 1);
        headers.add("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        headers.add("Content-Range", String.format("bytes %d-%d/%d", rangeStart, rangeEnd, fileSize));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
        final long startPoint = rangeStart, endPoint = rangeEnd;
        StreamingResponseBody streamingResponseBody = os -> {
            try (RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath.toFile(), "r")) {
                long pos = startPoint;
                file.seek(pos);
                while (pos < endPoint) {
                    file.read(buffer);
                    os.write(buffer);
                    pos += buffer.length;
                }
                os.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.info("stream close by client.");
                // e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        return new ResponseEntity<>(streamingResponseBody, headers, HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT);
    }

// and undertow related configuration in application.yml
  undertow:
    max-http-post-size: -1
    buffer-size: 512
    direct-buffers: true
    threads:
      io: 8
      worker: 256
```

My springboot version is 2.7.7, and same with the undertow. Is that exception because of undertow? I know this exception will not affect the normal function of my program, but I still want to be aware of how it occurred and fix it as posible.